# Extract very long url from string in VB

Tags: regex, vb.net

I'm trying to extract an url from a string with regex. But it's always telling me "Identifier expected".

My code looks like this:

```
Dim url As String = Regex.Match(StringToExtractFrom, "(?<=:").*(?="})").value
```

and the string looks like this:

```
{"http_url":"https://example.com/s45hHdfgrjrm.html?f10843jkg9023f5a\Auth=3kltrejmle"}
```

and I want to extract this:

```
https://example.com/s45hHdfgrjrm.html?f10843jkg9023f5a\Auth=3kltrejmle
```

Would be awesome if someone can help me out!

Comment: I'm not sure vb is really liking `"(?<=:").*(?="})"` as one string... Have you tried escaping the double quotes: `"(?<=:"").*(?=""})"`?

Comment: Oh really man.. This already did the job! A huge thanks!

Comment: I suppose, VB.NET <4 built-in JSON serializer/deserializer also worth a shot :}

Comment: @Robin you should add that as an answer

Answer (score 0):

You should try JSON parser, or the Regex solution by Robin (that already helped you), but you can do it in a more simpler and manual way too:

```
Dim index As Integer = jsonStr.IndexOf(":"c) + 2
url = jsonStr.Substring(index, jsonStr.LastIndexOf(""""c) - index)
```